# Searching through an array and putting it into UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Right now I have an array that has around 100000 elements. I've created a search bar for it but I think due to the number of elements that it is parsing through my phone lags when using the search bar. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How are you searching for the items? Only way I can think of to speed it up is to use a more efficient searching algorithm

Comment: I'm using the array filter for the search I have an array named `dictionary` and I call `self.dictionary.filter({( ...)})` but I'm not sure that this is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NSPredicate`?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'a'"];
NSArray *beginWithA = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
// beginWithA contains { @"Adam" }.

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];
[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
// array now contains { @"Nick", @"Ben", @"Melissa" }
```

That being said, with 100000 elements, wouldn't a persistent store make more sense?

Comment: Currently I'm loading the Table View from CoreData, what is persistent store?

Comment: Take a look at realm.io, I prefer it over core data.

Comment: I was wondering if it was because I'm loading everything in my viewDidLoad that's why it is taking so long? Maybe there is some way to cache it?

Comment: Try wrapping your search in a `dispatch_async` block

Comment: If it wouldn't be too much trouble would you mind giving me some sample code?